# C++ design question on traversing binary trees

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I have a binary tree T which I would like to copy to another tree.

Suppose I have  a visit method that gets evaluated at every node:

```
struct visit 
{
 virtual void operator() (node* n)=0;

};
```

and I have a  visitor algorithm

```
void visitor(node* t, visit& v)
{
//do a preorder traversal using stack or recursion
 if (!t) return;
 v(t);
 visitor(t->left, v);
 visitor(t->right, v);

}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. I settled on using the functor based approach because  I see that boost graph does this (vertex visitors). Also I tend to repeat the same code to traverse the tree and do different things
   at each node. Is this a good design to get rid of duplicated code? What other alternative designs are there?
2. How do I use this to create a new binary tree from an existing one? I can keep a stack on the
   visit functor if I want, but it gets tied to the algorithm in visitor.
3. How would I incorporate postorder traversals here ? Another functor class?

Comment: Is this homework?  If it is tag it as such

Comment: That looks like at least three questions =)

Comment: No not homework at all. Wish it was! Too old to be doing homework.
I feel like I am being carded for buying cigarettes. Thank you :-)

Comment: @user231536 If its not homework, why are you writing your own binary tree class?

Comment: Why not make `visitor` a template function, so you don't force everything to inherit from visit?

Comment: @Neil: He might have special concerns, like operating out of a shared mapped disk file. I've done that, it's impossible (or so it seems to me) to make STL containers behave properly.

Comment: @Neil I wrote a binary tree class for the purpose of learning on my own long before I attended university. There's nothing unusual about that.

Comment: @Neil: is that a joke question?! Writing a binary tree implementation is perfectly reasonable for a lot of scenarios where existing implementations don’t fit.

Comment: @Red Firstly, please change your name back! Secondly - well if you say so. I somehow seem to have managed not to have to write my own binary trees for the past I don't know how many years, except when teaching and forced to by the syllabus. But perhaps I've lead a delicate and protected life.

Comment: @Neil: I can’t. :-( Only one change of name per month allowed. Needless to say, I saw this too late.

Comment: @Red So red-faced as well as red-nosed, eh?

Answer (score 1):

3: Create an additional method for each type of traversal you want to do and rearrange the visitor calls:

```
void preorder_visitor(node* t, visit& v)
{
 if (!t) return;
 v(t);
 visitor(t->left, v);
 visitor(t->right, v);
}

void postorder_visitor(node* t, visit& v)
{
 if (!t) return;
 visitor(t->left, v);
 visitor(t->right, v);
 v(t);
}
```

Comment: It's possible to combine them into a single method, but that's quite a bit harder than it appears to be at first glance and really isn't worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

1. Subclass the visitor and provide different visitors for each individual task, and merge like (or related) tasks into the same visitor.  The best approach depends heavily on what you are attempting to do.
2. A visitor can construct a different tree.  As it visits nodes, it builds the new node copies and links them in the "correct" order.
3. You rewrite the order in which the nodes are visited.

A visitor is a technique.  It looks like you've confused the technique with a particular solution.  Using a visitor means that some navigation services are provided by the data structure which will communicate with an external object (the visitor) by call-back.